# Any way to profile C++ MEX code NOT built with the 'Mex' command?

Tags: c++, matlab, profiling, mex

I need to profile some C++ Mex code.

It is built with G++, using arguments similar to those `mex` would pass. I can absolutely pass -o0 and -g or -g3, no problem.

The current solutions I have found:

- [MATLAB Profiler](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/profile-generated-mex-functions-using-matlab-profiler.html) - Requires it was built with `mex`. I tried this myself to no avail. (It provided no information)
- [Visual Studio](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/277171-profiling-mex-in-windows) - Also apparently requires that it was built with `mex`. I tried this myself with [these results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743294/visual-studio-community-2019-hangs-during-preparing-data-for-performance-profi) sadly. (It just froze)
- [MATLAB Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220250/how-do-i-profile-a-mex-function-in-matlab) - Apparently also requires it was built with `mex`.
- Building a C++ driver for it instead of the MATLAB script is likely not an option, as the script is complex and does significant setup (some with other mex files) before the section I want is called.

Is there anything that will work with MEX files not built with `mex`?

Comment: You want to profile it with its inside functions or just know how long it takes in general?

Comment: It would be best to be able to run the MATLAB script that calls the MEX files, and see what % of the runtime was spent in the C++ code, as well as by function or by line. That's asking a lot, but it would be ideal. Maybe the easiest way is just to wrap the functions in some C-style timing calls and use mexprintf() to print out the time taken. Not fine-grained but perhaps the best that can be done.

Comment: When using the `mex` script to compile, it calls `g++` or whatever other compiler you have configured. So I don't think that "Requires it was built with `mex`" is correct. Likely, you are not using all the right flags, or you are having a different issue altogether.

Comment: @TylerShellberg I am asking because well, `tic; somecppfun();toc;` works